# how to clear the list after using

Tags: kotlin

This is how I clear list after using, invalidDestination.clear(), but each time after I enter some invalid input, it will shows the previous error message.

for example

1st error message

```
"add fields abcd"
```

second time when I enter an invalid data like bcda, it should only return "add fields bcda", but the error message is, I already clear the list, what else should I do?

```
"add fields abcd, bcda"
```

```
 private val validationErrors = mutableSetOf<ValidationError>()

private fun validateConfigTypeBduilder(configTypeBuilderList: List<ConfigTypeBuilder>, ruleAttributes: List<String>, destinationFieldList: List<String>) {
if (ruleAttributes.isNotEmpty()) {

var invalidDestination = mutableListOf<String>()

for (destinationField in destinationFieldList) {
        if (!ruleAttributes.contains(destinationField)) {
                invalidDestination.add(destinationField)
            }
         }

if (invalidDestination.firstOrNull { invalidDestination.contains(configTypeBuilder.destinationField) } != null)
      addValidationError(""someMessage", "someMessage", $ADD_FIELDS $invalidDestination")
      invalidDestination.clear()
  }
}

private fun addValidationError(fieldPath: String, field: Any, error: String) {
        logDataPathValidationError(fieldPath, field, error)
        validationErrors.add(
            ValidationError(
                fieldPath,
                error
            )
        )
    }

internal fun logDataPathValidationError(dataPath: String, value: Any?, constraint: String) {
        logger.info("{} {} value violates {} constraint", dataPath, value, constraint)
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more context?
Looks like you are creating and populating a new list each time you enter a new field

Comment: @EricMartori that's all my code, any fix I can do?

Comment: Where is the `addValidationError` function? If that involves adding anything to the list then you should call this line `invalidDestination.clear()` before the function call

Comment: @gtxtreme I add addValidationError function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Eric's inspire, I realized I should add clear destinationFieldList not invalidDestination after the if loop, to make sure next time calling validateConfigTypeBduilder with empty  destinationFieldList

```
destinationFieldList.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are calling `validateConfigTypeBduilder` a new list called `invalidDestination` is created. Then in the first loop you populate that list.

Then inside the if statement *(the condition is a little weird the `firstOrNull` and the null check are irrelevant and removing them will produce the same result)* you call `addValidationError` which logs the message and then clear the list.

If you are calling `validateConfigTypeBduilder` with the full list `destinationFieldList` then the number of errors reported will increase, since the list is produced and populated inside the function.

The list is getting cleared properly, but your code stops using it after clearing it.

Instead of sending the whole list `addValidationError` (assuming the `invalidDestination` list is ordered) you can send only the last element.

Changing this:

```
if (invalidDestination.firstOrNull { invalidDestination.contains(configTypeBuilder.destinationField) } != null)
      addValidationError(""someMessage", "someMessage", $ADD_FIELDS $invalidDestination")
      invalidDestination.clear()
  }
```

to something like this:

```
invalidDestination.lastOrNull()?.let { 
  addValidationError(""someMessage", "someMessage", $ADD_FIELDS $it")
}
```

I don't fully understand you condition in the if statemente, so this is only an aproximation of the changes

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your comment, but I need to log all the error fields, not only the last one, your code only log the last one